# UnicodeEncodeError - works in Spyder but not when executed from terminal

Tags: python, string, unicode, beautifulsoup, codec

I'm using BeautifulSoup to Parse some html, with Spyder as my editor (both brilliant tools by the way!). The code runs fine in Spyder, but when I try to execute the .py file from terminal, I get an error:

```
file =  open('index.html','r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(file)
html = soup.prettify()
file1 =  open('index.html', 'wb')
file1.write(html)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 5632: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm running OPENSUSE on a linux server, with Spyder installed using zypper.
Does anyone have any suggestions what the problem might be?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because because before outputting the result (i.e writing it to the file) you must encode it first:

```
file1.write(html.encode('utf-8'))
```

See every file has an attribute `file.encoding`. To quote the docs:

> **file.encoding**
>
> The encoding that this file uses. When Unicode strings
>   are written to a file, they will be converted to byte strings using
>   this encoding. In addition, when the file is connected to a terminal,
>   the attribute gives the encoding that the terminal is likely to use
>   (that information might be incorrect if the user has misconfigured the
>   terminal). The attribute is read-only and may not be present on all
>   file-like objects. It may also be None, in which case the file uses
>   the system default encoding for converting Unicode strings.

See the last sentence? `soup.prettify` returns a Unicode object and given this error, I'm pretty sure you're using Python 2.7 because its `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is `ascii`.

Hope this helps!